# Is there a local canonical ensemble partition function for a Bose-Einstein gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, partition-function

The grand canonical partition function for a Bose-Einstein gas is
$$
Z_{\text{grand bos}}
=
\exp
\left(
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}
-\ln
\left(
1-e^{\beta(\mu-\epsilon_j)}
\right)g_j
\right)
$$
where $\beta$ is the reciprocal temperature, $\mu$ is the chemical potential, $\epsilon_j$ is the energy of state $j$, and $g_j$ is the degeneracy of state $j$. I can replace the exp function with its Taylor series to obtain
$$
Z_{\text{grand bos}}
=
\sum_{N=0}
\dfrac{1}{N!}
\left(
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}
-\ln
\left(
1-e^{\beta(\mu-\epsilon_j)}
\right)g_j
\right)^N
$$
This form of the partition function is very similar to the grand canonical partition of a classical gas 
$$
Z_{\text{grand classical}}
=
\sum_{N=0}
\dfrac{1}{N!}
\left(
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}
e^{\beta(\mu-\epsilon_j)}g_j
\right)^N
$$
where $N$ represents the number of particles for different instances of the same gas. If I know how many particles are in my gas, but I do not know what its chemical potential is, I can remove the sum over $N$ to obtain the classical local ensemble
$$
Z_{\text{local classical}}
=
\dfrac{1}{N!}
\left(
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}
e^{\beta(-\epsilon_j)}g_j
\right)^N
$$
where the presence of $\mu$ is redundant as a homogeneous scalar. With this classical logic I ask the question, can I also interpret $N$ in the Bose-Einstein grand partition function as the number of particles for a given instance of the gas and express its local ensemble equivalent as
$$
Z_{\text{local bos}}
=
\dfrac{1}{N!}
\left(
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}
-\ln
\left(
1-e^{\beta(\mu-\epsilon_j)}
\right)g_j
\right)^N
$$
or does there not exist such a form?